# ON/OFF button keeps toggling through states on every touch

Tags: button, sprite-kit

I don´t know what I´m doing wrong, maybe I'm sitting here way too long on my project. However, I set up a settings menu in my menuScene and I want to create a simple on-off button with a texture with this code:

```
if ([settingsMenuNode.name isEqualToString:@"checkmark1"]) {

        if (self.checkmarkBanner == NO) {
            [self.menuCheckmark1 setTexture:[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"menuCheckmark"]];
            self.checkmarkBanner = YES;
            NSLog(@"YES");
        }

        if (self.checkmarkBanner == YES) {
            [self.menuCheckmark1 setTexture:[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"menuCheckmarkEmpty"]];
            self.checkmarkBanner = NO;
            NSLog(@"NO");
        }

    }
```

every time I touch on the node, I get both logs for ON & OFF at the same time.

can anyone please help me out?

checkmarkBanner is my BOOL just to set whether a banner notification during the game appears or not.

Comment: ok, for someone who had the same problems.. just add a "return;" after each log...

Comment: Tip: next time set a breakpoint and step through. You would have noticed the problem right away.

Comment: @NeoGER89 If that's how you solved the problem, you should post it as an answer. And for future reference, there's no need for the return statements. This code could easily be rewritten with the contents of the second if statement inside an else clause on the first if statement.

Answer (score 1):

ok, thank you for your quick answers, so i´ve updated my code to this (i added some NSUserDefaults):

```
//CheckMarkBanner
    if ([settingsMenuNode.name isEqualToString:@"checkmarkBanner"]) {

        if (self.checkmarkBanner == YES) {
            [self.menuCheckmark1 setTexture:[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"menuCheckmarkEmpty"]];
            NSString *offString = @"NO";
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:offString forKey:@"checkmark1Banner"];
            self.checkmarkBanner = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]stringForKey:@"checkmark1Banner"]boolValue];
            NSLog(@"Banner NO");

        }

        else {
            [self.menuCheckmark1 setTexture:[SKTexture textureWithImageNamed:@"menuCheckmark"]];
            NSString *onString = @"YES";
            [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]setObject:onString forKey:@"checkmark1Banner"];
            self.checkmarkBanner = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]stringForKey:@"checkmark1Banner"]boolValue];
            NSLog(@"Banner YES");

        }
    }
```